# Where query in Grails not returning records

Tags: grails, where-clause

Update:  I found the problem.  I needed to save the "train" domain as follows.

train.save(flush: true)

I needed to provide a flush, as well.

I edited to include the information requested.  Thanks.

I have two domain classes as follows.

```
class Train {

    String name
    static hasMany = [passengers: Person]
    . . .

}

class Person {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    . . .
}
```

I am trying to use a where query to look for passengers with a given first name. Here is the full integration test code. The first query, looking for the passenger, does not work.  The second one, looking for the train by name, works.

I am using Grails 2.2.1 and am running the test inside of my IDE, Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.2.  I am not bootstrapping data, but am adding data in the test.  Please see the testSomething code below.

Here is the test code.

```
import grails.converters.*
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*

class TrainIntegrationTests {

    @Before
    void setUp() {

        // Setup logic here

    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    @Test
    void testSomething() {

        def person1 = new Person()
        person1.firstName = "George"
        person1.lastName = "Romero"
        person1.save();

        println "person1.id: " + person1.id

        def person2 = new Person()
        person2.firstName = "Jane"
        person2.lastName = "Smith"
        person2.save();

        def train = new Train()
        train.name = "This Train"
        train.addToPassengers(person1)
        train.addToPassengers(person2)
        train.save()

        // This prints out 2.
        println "passengers size" + train.passengers.size()

        // This does not work.  No results are returned.
        def query = Train.where {
            passengers {
                firstName == 'George'
            }
        }
        def qResults = query.list()
        // No results
        println "qResults: " + qResults


        // This does work.  Results returned.
        def query1 = Train.where {
            name == 'This Train'
        }
        def qResults1 = query1.list()
        // Returns results.
        println "qResults1: " + qResults1


        // Don't really care about assert results yet.
        // Just looking at the print outs and seeing how this all works.
        assert true

    }

}
```

What am I missing in the passengers query?

Comment: Are you bootstrapping test data for your tests?  Are you sure the data is there?

Comment: What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Add the integration test to the question as well.

Comment: Please add the integration test or explain where you're adding some records to test against.  With your code here, we never see when/how 'George' is saved.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the full integration test code and Grails version info.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: def query = Train.where {
            passengers.firstName == 'George'
        }   what happens with this ?

Comment: vahid, your suggestion does not work.  The results are still empty.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I found the problem.  I needed to save with a flush, as well.

Instead of . . .

```
train.save()
```

I used . . .

```
train.save(flush: true)
```

The query began working after that.